# Value counts for specific items in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe (df) of messages that appears similar the following:

```
From                To
person1@gmail.com   stranger1@gmail.com
person2@gmail.com   stranger1@gmail.com, stranger2@gmail.com
person3@gmail.com   person1@gmail.com, stranger2@gmail.com
```

I want to count the amount of times each email appears from a specific list. My list being:

```
lst = ['person1@gmail.com', 'stranger2@gmail.com', 'person3@gmail.com']
```

I'm hoping to receive a dataframe/series/dictionary with a result like this:

```
list_item              Total_Count
person1@gmail.com      2
stranger2@gmail.com    2
person3@gmail.com      1
```

I'm tried several different things, but haven't succeeded. I thought I could try something like the for loop below (it returns a Syntax Error), but I cannot figure out the right way to write it.

```
for To,From in zip(df.To, df.From): 
    for item in lst:
        if To,From contains item in emails:
            Count(item)
```

Should this type of task be accomplished with a for loop or are there out of the box pandas methods that could solve this easier?

Comment: Don't use "list" to name variables. That name has already been taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `stack`-based

Split your `To` column, `stack` everything and then do a `value_counts`:

```
v = pd.concat([df.From, df.To.str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1).stack()
v[v.isin(lst)].value_counts()

stranger2@gmail.com    2
person1@gmail.com      2
person3@gmail.com      1
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `melt`

Another option is to use `melt`:

```
v = (df.set_index('From')
      .To.str.split(', ', expand=True)
      .reset_index()
      .melt()['value']
)
v[v.isin(lst)].value_counts()

stranger2@gmail.com    2
person1@gmail.com      2
person3@gmail.com      1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Note that `set_index` + `str.split` + `reset_index` is synonymous to `pd.concat([...])`...

Comment: Wow, thanks! You solved that so quickly! I had never used .stack() before this. I'll definitely be using it more in the future.

Before seeing .stack(), I kept trying to change the column into a Series so that I could flatten it - not much luck there.

Comment: @coldspeed Can you tell me something? The dataframe given in this question. How did you make it? You typed it all by yourself or is there an easy way to construct it? For trying it out, I mean.

Comment: @J...S copy the text in the question and then run `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python')`

Comment: @coldspeed Whoa! And so far I've been trying to edit the stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @J...S no worries, it blew my mind when I first discovered it too ;)